# Include extra files to build projects but not to modify project files

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild

I want to write custom msbuild project file a.proj to call the project files Project1/Project1.csproj and Project2/Project2.csproj.
I do not want to change csproj because they are generated by VS.

I want to inject extra source file abc.cs when compiling Project1.csproj and Project2.csproj

This does not work. Could you suggest ways to do that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="abc.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
    <MSBuild Projects="Project1/Project1.csproj" />
    <MSBuild Projects="Project2/Project2.csproj" />
</Project>
```

Comment: Where is that extra file supposed to be built into? Each project usually builds its own binary.

Comment: would a more real world example be including a boilerplate AssemblyInfo.cs in all of your projects with versioning information?